# Read td values using prototype

Tags: html, prototypejs

I would like to read the values of HTML td using prototype. For example, say you have a table as follows

```
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>orange</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>bus</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to read the values - apple, orange, car and bus alone. I am unable to find a 
way to do it? Any help would be of great help.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
var values = $$('#myTable td').collect(function(element) {
  // stripTags(), if you're only interested in the actual content
  return element.innerHTML.stripTags();
});
```

Comment: Sorry to ask an extended question here - In the same case, how do I retrieve the last tr element in the table?

Comment: Um... `children = $$('#myTable tr'); last_tr = children.pop()`

Answer (score 2):

The following returns an array of strings.

```
$$('#myTable td').pluck('innerHTML');
```

Comment: I would call that brevity, because it's shorter.